# DNS is to slow, slow respond between server to Instagram API

Tags: domain-name-system, google, linode

I have app who is based on Instagram API,
problem is because connection between my server and Instagram API is slow,
e.g.
OVH = 300ms - 400ms
Linode = 400ms - 500ms
Hetzner = 500ms - 600ms

I try google public DNS and default hosting DNS but both is slow,
In my case I do 2 requests and this take a lot time, sometimes more then 1.5sec,
Anyone can suggest some way for I improve my connection speed between server and Instagram API?

I saw this:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/namebench/
this only help with google api or can help with instagram to?

Comment: What exactly is it that is slow? You talk both about DNS and about connections to the Instagram API - which is it, or is it both? What diagnostics have you tried to run? What logs do you have? What is the connection speed you expect from your provider? What has the provider said when you questioned the slow connection times? Are they slow only for your application or for other things too?

Answer (score -1):

Why you thing DNS slow make your connection slow? You can change hosts file of your OS to check it. After you change hosts file, your PC will not connect to DNS server to query DNS anymore.

Comment: If he is using a third-party API, creating that kind of static mapping might lead to the app breaking - I think adding a local caching resolver might be a better way to address a potential slow DNS issue, if that is indeed the problem.